# Visual Studio Code v1.37 is not underlining errors

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode editor v1.37 for my angular 6 app. Now its stopped  underlining errors (wavy red squiggles).In json files showing errors but typescript and js files are not showing errors. All my projects are affected. I installed new version... but still it remains same.

Comment: Can you post your tslint.json please

Comment: I have attached tslint.json in this link-> https://notepad.pw/12333333333vsc

Comment: Can you try changing your first line in tslint to this:  `"extends": "tslint:recommended",
    "rulesDirectory": ["codelyzer", "rxjs-tslint"],` and reload vscode

Comment: try this link: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-tslint/issues/254#issuecomment-329115040

Comment: I changed....but it didnt work...